# Loading XDocument Descendants into a .NET MVC 3 Model

Tags: .net, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-xml

I have a repository that attempts to load an XML document into a class. This all seems to go alright until I attempt to access the descendants elements in the map config section.

This is the structure of the XML file:

```
 <apps>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <engineversion>1.0</engineversion>
    <mapconfig>
      <minzoom>3</minzoom>
      <maxzoom>18</maxzoom>
      <startcenterlat>-28</startcenterlat>
      <startcenterlng>135</startcenterlng>
      <startzoom>3</startzoom>
    </mapconfig>
  </item>
</apps>
```

And this is the repository method on my controller:

```
public AppRepository()
{
    allApps = new List<App>();

    appData = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Apps.xml"));

    var apps = from app in appData.Descendants("item")
                select new App(
                    (int)app.Element("id"),
                    (float)app.Element("engineversion"),
                    new MapConfig (
                        (int)app.Descendants("mapconfig").Descendants("minzoom").FirstOrDefault(),
                        (int)app.Descendants("mapconfig").Descendants("maxzoom").FirstOrDefault(),
                        (float)app.Descendants("mapconfig").Descendants("startcenterlat").FirstOrDefault(),
                        (float)app.Descendants("mapconfig").Descendants("startcenterlng").FirstOrDefault(),
                        (int)app.Descendants("mapconfig").Descendants("startzoom").FirstOrDefault()
                    )
                );

    allApps.AddRange(apps.ToList<App>());

}
```

This seems to result in the id and engine version values correctly being read into the App object however the MapConfig object seems to just have 0 set as the value of all the elements.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact structure of the XML file, with no namespaces etc? Also, why are you using `Descendants()` rather than just `Element`? It's not like you're actually trying to go down multiple levels, and presumably `<mapconfig>` is a required element?

Comment: The code you showed works with the XML you showed.

Comment: Yeah Jon that's the exact structure. Dan the code works - however as I said it dosent successfully read in the values of the mapconfig child nodes.

Comment: @fencehead2 it *does* read the values successfully. Just check the constructors of `App` and `MapConfig` which you haven't shown us.